# virtual segment memory/core allocation in Apache Hawq

Tags: hawq

I am trying to tweak below Hawq configurations at session level for a query-

```
SET hawq_rm_stmt_nvseg = 40;
SET hawq_rm_stmt_vseg_memory = '4gb';
```

Hawq is running on Yarn resource manager with

```
Minumum Hawq queue Used capacity 5%
hawq_rm_nvseg_perquery_perseg_limit = 6 
hawq_rm_min_resource_perseg = 4
```

When running my query i see only 30 containers being launched. Should it not be 40 containers (1 core per virtual segments)? Please help me understand how virtual segments memory or cores are allocated?

Answer (score 1):

hawq_rm_stmt_nvseg is a quota limit.  By default, this is 0.  So setting this to 40 won't increase the number of vsegs but instead, limit it.

hawq_rm_nvseg_perquery_perseg_limit controls how many vsegs can be created and you are using the default of 6.  So the number of vsegs should be 6 * number of nodes.  If you see 30, then you probably have 5 nodes.

If you are using randomly distributed tables, you can increase hawq_rm_nvseg_perquery_perseg_limit to get more vsegs to work on your query.

If you are using hash distributed tables, you can recreate the table with a larger bucketnum value which will give you more vsegs when you query it.

Comment: Number of nodes (Physical HAWQ segments) are 10. So ideally it should be 40 vsegs (4 per Physical seg) resulting into 40 yarn containers but i am seeing 30 yarn containers. Am i missing anything here?

Comment: I noticed you have hawq_rm_min_resource_perseg set to 4 so 4*10 = 40.  The number of vsegs is dynamic and based on the table being accessed.  A small table won't need to use more vsegs.  More detail on Yarn integration: http://hdb.docs.pivotal.io/220/hawq/resourcemgmt/YARNIntegration.html